# forking ssh using python paramiko

Tags: python, linux, ssh, fork, paramiko

I am using the python module Paramiko to ssh to a linux box and execute two C programs.
Program1 generates a signal on a DAQ device on a trigger. It waits for the trigger and terminates in 5 seconds.
Program2 generates the trigger.

Here is my Python class:

```
class test:
    server = "localhost"
    username = "root"
    password = "12345"
    def ssh (self, cmd = ""):
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            ssh.connect(self.server,username=self.username,password=self.password)
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
            result = stdout.read().splitlines()
            if len(result)!= 0:
                return result
            else:
                return -1

test.ssh("program1")
test.ssh("program2")
```

The problem is that program2 is being executed after program1 has been already terminated, so it doesn't generate anything.
Is there a way I can run program2 faster than program1 is done?
I have tried

```
test.ssh("program1 &")
test.ssh("program2")
```

but to no avail. If I run these programs manually in two terminal shells, then it works fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: you can try to use python thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use threading or multiprocessing to execute the both the programs in different sessions

```
import multiprocessing

input = ["program1","program2"]   

for i in range(2):
    p = mutiprocessing.Process(target=test.ssh,args=(input[i],))
    p.start()
    processlist.append(p)

for p in processlist:
    p.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try running them in the same SSH session: `test.ssh("program1 & program2")`. This way you wouldn't be paying twice for all the set-up and tear-down that you do `test.ssh`.

Comment: I don't need this behavior. I would like to run test.ssh("program2") at any time, not immediately after test.ssh("program1")